# sensors-detect does not discover all sensors on Lenovo IdeaPad Y510p

Tags: lenovo, fan, temperature

My **sensors** readings never read values for next two sensors:

**acpitz-virtual-0** always show 0 degrees for **temp1**

**thinkpad-isa-0000** always show **0 RPM**

```
drakone@b4da55:~$ sensors
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:         +0.0°C  (crit = +127.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +49.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:         +50.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:         +46.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:         +49.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:         +45.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

thinkpad-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
fan1:           0 RPM
```

**sensors-detect** finds **core-temp** and family `National Semiconductor/ITE **unknown chip with ID 0x8586**

```
drakone@b4da55:~$ sudo sensors-detect 
# sensors-detect revision 6170 (2013-05-20 21:25:22 +0200)
# System: LENOVO 20217 [Lenovo IdeaPad Y510P] (laptop)
# Board: LENOVO VIQY0Y1

This program will help you determine which kernel modules you need
to load to use lm_sensors most effectively. It is generally safe
and recommended to accept the default answers to all questions,
unless you know what you're doing.

Some south bridges, CPUs or memory controllers contain embedded sensors.
Do you want to scan for them? This is totally safe. (YES/no): 
Module cpuid loaded successfully.
Silicon Integrated Systems SIS5595...                       No
VIA VT82C686 Integrated Sensors...                          No
VIA VT8231 Integrated Sensors...                            No
AMD K8 thermal sensors...                                   No
AMD Family 10h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 11h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 12h and 14h thermal sensors...                   No
AMD Family 15h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 15h power sensors...                             No
AMD Family 16h power sensors...                             No
Intel digital thermal sensor...                             Success!
    (driver `coretemp')
Intel AMB FB-DIMM thermal sensor...                         No
VIA C7 thermal sensor...                                    No
VIA Nano thermal sensor...                                  No

Some Super I/O chips contain embedded sensors. We have to write to
standard I/O ports to probe them. This is usually safe.
Do you want to scan for Super I/O sensors? (YES/no): 
Probing for Super-I/O at 0x2e/0x2f
Trying family `National Semiconductor/ITE'...               No
Trying family `SMSC'...                                     No
Trying family `VIA/Winbond/Nuvoton/Fintek'...               No
Trying family `ITE'...                                      No
Probing for Super-I/O at 0x4e/0x4f
Trying family `National Semiconductor/ITE'...               Yes
Found unknown chip with ID 0x8586

Some hardware monitoring chips are accessible through the ISA I/O ports.
We have to write to arbitrary I/O ports to probe them. This is usually
safe though. Yes, you do have ISA I/O ports even if you do not have any
ISA slots! Do you want to scan the ISA I/O ports? (YES/no): 
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM78' at 0x290...       No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM79' at 0x290...       No
Probing for `Winbond W83781D' at 0x290...                   No
Probing for `Winbond W83782D' at 0x290...                   No

Lastly, we can probe the I2C/SMBus adapters for connected hardware
monitoring devices. This is the most risky part, and while it works
reasonably well on most systems, it has been reported to cause trouble
on some systems.
Do you want to probe the I2C/SMBus adapters now? (YES/no): 
Using driver `i2c-i801' for device 0000:00:1f.3: Intel Lynx Point (PCH)
Module i2c-i801 loaded successfully.
Module i2c-dev loaded successfully.

Next adapter: NVIDIA i2c adapter 0 at 1:00.0 (i2c-0)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): 

Next adapter: NVIDIA i2c adapter 1 at 1:00.0 (i2c-1)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): 

Next adapter: NVIDIA i2c adapter 2 at 1:00.0 (i2c-2)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): 

Next adapter: NVIDIA i2c adapter 7 at 1:00.0 (i2c-3)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): 

Next adapter: NVIDIA i2c adapter 8 at 1:00.0 (i2c-4)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): 

Next adapter: NVIDIA i2c adapter 11 at 1:00.0 (i2c-5)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): 

Next adapter: NVIDIA i2c adapter 0 at 7:00.0 (i2c-6)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): 

Next adapter: NVIDIA i2c adapter 1 at 7:00.0 (i2c-7)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): 

Next adapter: NVIDIA i2c adapter 2 at 7:00.0 (i2c-8)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): 

Next adapter: SMBus I801 adapter at 6000 (i2c-9)
Do you want to scan it? (YES/no/selectively): 
Client found at address 0x50
Probing for `Analog Devices ADM1033'...                     No
Probing for `Analog Devices ADM1034'...                     No
Probing for `SPD EEPROM'...                                 Yes
    (confidence 8, not a hardware monitoring chip)
Probing for `EDID EEPROM'...                                No
Client found at address 0x52
Probing for `Analog Devices ADM1033'...                     No
Probing for `Analog Devices ADM1034'...                     No
Probing for `SPD EEPROM'...                                 Yes
    (confidence 8, not a hardware monitoring chip)

Now follows a summary of the probes I have just done.
Just press ENTER to continue: 

Driver `coretemp':
  * Chip `Intel digital thermal sensor' (confidence: 9)

To load everything that is needed, add this to /etc/modules:
#----cut here----
# Chip drivers
coretemp
#----cut here----
If you have some drivers built into your kernel, the list above will
contain too many modules. Skip the appropriate ones!

Do you want to add these lines automatically to /etc/modules? (yes/NO)

Unloading i2c-dev... OK
Unloading i2c-i801... OK
Unloading cpuid... OK
```

What I need to do to get proper sensor readings in my Ubuntu 14.04 (cpu fan speed, board temperature...)?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find any solution? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: no, i eventually gave up. it does not overheat anymore so I do not care - now its cold :)

Comment: mine is also 'cold' nowadays, because I ended up disabling the turbo boost for the CPU (have done this one year ago or so) and I get around 45-50 C while idle and 58-68 C while working, compared to 80+ with turbo boost enabled. I wish there was a solution for this...

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing you can do about reading the chip directly since it is unknown, which means not supported yet.

As for the acpi readings, it seems your acpi bios is broken so you might check if they have a bios update you can install to fix it.